# Axios Post request from my react app to the express server giving error 500

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, post, axios

I am trying to make a post request from my react app to the express server. On making the post request from postman works fine but when I make it from my react app It gives error 500 (Internal server error)

This is my client side code-

```
function signUpWithEmail(e,email,password,ConfirmPassword,userHandle) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let params = {
        email: email,  
        password: password,
        ConfirmPassword: ConfirmPassword,
        userHandle: userHandle
      }

    let res = axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:3031/signUp/',
        data : params,
         headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
         },
         validateStatus: (status) => {
             return true
         },
        })
      .then(() => console.log('Created'))
      .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.message)
      })
```

This is my server code

```
`const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const express = require('express')
 const app = express()
 const port = 3031;  
 const cors = require('cors');
 const { signup } = require('./server/users'); 
 const { login, getAuthenticatedUser } = require('./server/users');
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000/");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});

 app.use(cors())

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))
app.post('/signUp',cors(),signup);
app.post('/login', login);
```

Comment: dear it's 500, something in your backend function is not right

Comment: And.... what is the stack trace for your server's internal error? Also, why in the world are you _sending_ a CORS header TO your server?

Comment: @Chase sending cors error was out of frustration as nothing was working. I will remove it

Comment: @imranhaider What can be error as on making request on postman it is working fine